# Add active class to first slide in an array where the html is being dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I am creating a JS slider HTML dynamically, but I can't figure out how to add the `active` class to the first object in the array. This is the last thing I tried, any ideas? The data coming from an array in location.js.

All the slides are displaying on the screen via the loop - what I am trying to do is target the very first slide by adding a thick border around it, but the `dislayFirstSlide` function doesn't work.

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_inner"></div>
</div>
```

```js
const slideInner = document.querySelector(".slider_inner");
const main_slide = document.createElement("div");
main_slide.setAttribute('class', 'slide');
slideInner.appendChild(main_slide);

const mainSlide = document.querySelector(".slide");

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const showMainSlide = locations.map((location, index) => {
    return `
      <div class="main_slide_wrapper" key=${location.id}>
        <div class="main_slide_item">
          <div class="slide-body-image" style="background: url(${location.image});">
            <h5 class="card-title">${location.title}</h5>
            <a href=${location.ctaLink}>Go</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
  });

  mainSlide.innerHTML = showMainSlide;
});

displayFirstSlide();

function displayFirstSlide() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('main_slide_wrapper')[0].classList.add('active').style.border = '10px solid blue !important';
}
```

Comment: *'I am trying to do is target the very first slide by adding a thick border around it'* Tried some CSS? `.main_slide_wrapper:first-child { border: 2px solid #000; }`

Comment: Yes of course. The point is I want to target the first slide dynamically with javascript...

Comment: In the `map()` call you have access to `index`. It will be `0` for the first element in the array.

Comment: Hi, So as per my ``` displayFirstSlide();

function displayFirstSlide() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('main_slide_wrapper')[0].classList.add('active').style.border = '10px solid blue !important';
} ``` is that not a way to target the first object and add an active class to it?

Comment: You can't do `.classList.add('active').style.border = ...` to begin with, because the `add` method does not have a return value; so method chaining is not possible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh got it, this does what I want it to do

````
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const showMainSlide = locations.map((location, index) => {
        return `
                <div class="main_slide_wrapper" key=${location.id}>
                <div class="main_slide_item">
                    <div class="slide-body-image" style="background: url(${location.image});">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${location.title}</h5>
                        <a href=${location.ctaLink}>Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>`
    });

    mainSlide.innerHTML = showMainSlide;

    displayFirstSlide();
    function displayFirstSlide() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('main_slide_wrapper')[0].classList.add('active');
    }
}); 

``` much appreciate the responses. Cheers.
````